# Proof of x = 0 modulo 3 only if the sum of its digits 0 modulo 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Okey, lets beggin from a helpfull proposition I've already proved: 
$$$$ if $a_i\equiv b_i\:\forall 0\le i\le m$ then to any $m$ numbers: $p_1,p_2,...,p_m\in \mathbb{Z}$ 
$$\sum _{i=0}^m\left(k_ia_i\right)=\sum _{i=0}^m\left(k_ib_i\right)$$

Now, what I want to prove, is: for number $x$ who's digits are: $x_m...x_0$ 
$$x\equiv 0\left(mod\:3\right)\:\:<==>\:\:\sum \:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i\right)\equiv 0\left(mod\:3\right)$$ $$$$ I guess the same exmaple with modulo 11 is the same proof.

So, in the first direction, we'll treat $\sum \:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i\right)\equiv 0\left(mod\:3\right)$ as given data and we'll prove $x\equiv \:0\left(mod\:3\right)\:$

That direction of proof is simple:
As to the first proposition, we'll take $k_0=10^0,\:k_1=10^1,...,\:k_m=10^m$ and accroding to it: $$\sum \:\:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i10^i\right)\equiv \:\sum \:\:_{i=0}^m\left(0\cdot \:10^i\right)\left(mod\:3\right)$$ then also $$\sum \:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i10^i\right)\equiv 0\left(mod\:3\right)$$ As we want.

Now, in second direction, i have a little trouble:
Now we are given: $x\equiv \:0\left(mod\:3\right)\:$ and we want to prove: $$\sum \:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i\right)\equiv 0\left(mod\:3\right)$$

So, from the data that is given we can conclude that:
$$x=\sum \:\:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i\cdot 10^i\right)\equiv \:0\left(mod\:3\right)$$

And from here I dont sure how to get rid of the $10^i$, because the first proposition as i understand doesnt work on both directions (am I wrong?), because if n is a devider of a sum, we dont know for sure if it devides every element or only the sum of it, it can be the second case either.

So how do I show that $$\sum \:\:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i\cdot 10^i\right)\equiv \:0\left(mod\:3\right)\:\:\:===>\:\:\sum \:\:\:_{i=0}^m\left(x_i\right)\equiv \:\:0\left(mod\:3\right)$$